# Accessing php webs app via the public ip of Azure VM

Tags: php, azure, wamp

We have a PHP app which we installed on Azure VM. It works fine locally and accessible.

```
The server at 104.xxx.xx.xx is taking too long to respond.
```

We have used WAMP Server to host it and all looks fine. We are however not able to access it over the public ip of the server.

We have tried a few things without any result.

Comment: Probably a firewall rule on the VM or the Azure Network Security Group (NSG).

Comment: While i ran IIS, the IIS homepage was accessible via public ip so probably the WAMP Configuration.

Comment: HTTP is by default port 80 and HTTPS is 443, and both servers can't listen on the same port, so Apache is either on a different port, or it failed to start on 80/443.

Comment: Yes disabled IIS prior to setting up WAMP. The inbound rule had 'Any' in protocol for the port 80. Changed to TCP and it went through. While i am half bald pulling my hairs through..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you can check if the port is listening with CMD comamnds `netstat -anbo`. If the port is listening on external address 0.0.0.0 then you can check if the firewall inside the Azure VM or NSG associated with the Azure VM NIC or subnet blocking it.

Navigated to the virtual machine --- networking ---inbound port rules to find the related NSG rules on the Azure portal.

You also can telnet the VM public IP address and port from the on-premise machine to validate the networking connection.

Comment: It was my bad, had the protocol set to 'any'  for port 80 in Inbound rule while testing for IIS and went with that. Changed to TCP and it works fine.Strange..thanks